# lcd byte array display

Tags: serial, lcd, array, rfid

when reading RFID(MIFARE) information using Arduino mega and display in serial monitor it works fine. But, when printing on 2004LCD only one information(Value) displays correctly. The other information Item Name display a decimal number. Could someone help on this?

```
 void Price(){
      block = 4;
      status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, 4, &key, &(mfrc522.uid)); 
      if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
        Serial.print(F("Authentication failed: "));
        Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
        return;
      }
      status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Read(block, buffer1, &len);  // ***Note down buffer1 within the bracket
      if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
        Serial.print(F("Reading failedl: "));
        Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
        return;
      }
             //Display price information...
      for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; i++)
      {
        if (buffer1[i] != 32) // if buffer1[i] not equal to 32
        {
          Serial.write(buffer1[i]);  //Price
         //lcd.write(buffer1[i]); 
          Value = buffer1[i];
          }
       } 
      Serial.print("/=");
      Serial.println(" ");
      sscanf(buffer1,"%d",&Value);
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.println(Value);
     
      
     }
    //==========================================================
    void Item(){ //----- Get & Display Item information
        block = 1;
     status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, 1, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
      if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
        Serial.print(F("Authentication failed: "));
        Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
        return;
      }
      status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Read(block, buffer2, &len);
      if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
        Serial.print(F("Reading failed: "));
        Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
        return;
      }
      for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; i++) { //
         Serial.write(buffer2[i]);       // Display Item
         lcd.write(buffer2[i]); 
         Item_Name=buffer2[i];
        } 
        sscanf(buffer2,"%s",&Item_Name);
       //sprintf(buffer2,"%d",&Item_Name);
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print(Item_Name);// displays numbers instead of "Fresh Milk 1Lt 
     }
```

[image: lcd]
[image: Serial op]

Comment: What is the data type of `Item_Name`?

Comment: data type is int

Comment: sscanf(buffer2,"%s",&Item_Name); works however return a number instead an string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:

```cpp
char buffer2[16];  // array of 16 chars
for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    do_something_with(buffer2[i]);  // handle one char at a time
}
```

Here we have an array of 16 cells, each having the `char` type (which I
assume is what you have). The loop goes through the array, handling one
cell a time. Within the loop, `buffer2[i]` represents the `char` being
currently handled.

Keep in mind that a `char` is just an 8-bit integer. It is somehow
implied that it is meant to represent a character, where 32 = `' '`
(space), 33 = `'!'`, 48 = `'0'`, 65 = `'A'` and so on (see [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)).
The Arduino `print()` methods do assume a `char` (unlike an `int`) is
intended to be displayed as a character.

Now your actual loop:

```cpp
int Item_Name;
for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    Serial.write(buffer2[i]);  // write the char on the serial port
    lcd.write(buffer2[i]);     // write the char on the LCD
    Item_Name=buffer2[i];      // store the char in a variable
}
```

This will print the contents of the buffer to both the serial port and
the LCD. You would have seen the expected message on the LCD if you did
not have `lcd.clear()` right after the loop.

```cpp
sscanf(buffer2, "%s", &Item_Name);
```

This means “extract from `buffer2` a sequence of contiguous
non-white-space characters, and store it in memory at the address of the
variable `ItemName`”. If the buffer contains “Fresh Milk 1Lt”, this will
write “Fresh” to that memory location. That is 6 bytes (5 letters and a
terminating NUL). Unfortunately, the compiler has only allocated 2 or
4 bytes of RAM for storing `ItemName` (depending on the Arduino model),
so this will write past the allocated storage, which is a type of bug
known as [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). Now your Arduino's memory is corrupted and
anything can happen.

```cpp
sprintf(buffer2, "%d", &Item_Name);
```

This tries to find within `byffer2` a textual representation of a
number, and store it into `Item_Name`. This is safe, but only makes
sense if the buffer contains a number, written as text, which is not the
case here.

```cpp
lcd.print(Item_Name);
```

This is asking the LCD to print an integer (namely `Item_Name`). It will
convert the integer to decimal text and print the corresponding digits
on the LCD.

Let's assume for example that `Item_Name` contains the numeric value
`32` (which is the ASCII representation of a space). `lcd.print()` will
convert that into a sequence of two characters: `'3'` and `'2'` (the
decimal representation of 32). It will then send those characters to the
LCD (ASCII values 51 and 50), and you will see the text “32”.

If you want to see the text contained within the buffer, the you can
either send the characters one by one (like you already did right before
`lcd.clear()`), or provide to `lcd.print()` a `char*` pointer with the
whole message:

```cpp
lcd.print(buffer2);
```

This assumes that the buffer is terminated with a NUL character. If it
is not, then you can either use the char-at-a-time method, or change
your code in order to put a NUL terminator in the buffer.

Comment: Thank you so much! it's working when i change the data type of buffer2 from byte array to character array